# Interface and exposing class as property

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am looking at this code from a peer of mine and am a little confused as to how this makes sense:

```
public class CA
{
    public CurrType CT {get; set;}
}

public interface ICharge
{
    CA a {get; set;}
    CurrType CT {get; set;}
}

public enum CurrType {X=0, Y=1}
public class Ch : ICharge
{
    public CA a {get; set;}
    public CurrType CT {get; set;}
}
```

I understand that interfaces contain properties but cant make any sense of the above code specifically:
1) Can the interface ICharge contain a class as a property?
2) Isnt some circular reference going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isnt some circular reference going on?

No, there is no circular reference going on.

> Can the interface ICharge contain a class as a property?

It sure can - why did you think it couldn't? This is perfectly normal usage - the interface is specifying that that property will contain an instance of that class (i.e. an object of that type). Why a class? Because classes are everywhere - even a lot of the basic .Net types are classes. A `string` is a class. You can't do everything with primitive value types :)

I can't answer why there is two different usages of `CurrType` in `Ch` (one at the root level, one in the `CA` instance), that's for you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks Slugster - any examples of why a class is used as a property within Interface ?? meaning advantages etc?

Comment: With regards to 2 diff usages :) agree - need to find out that myself

Comment: @Patrick I've expanded my answer a little. To be honest the question in your comment puzzles me because it is a common everyday thing to do this, so I'm not sure why you think it shouldn't be done? Is it because you don't understand interfaces fully?

Comment: your expanded explanation is very helpful. Thanks